# Breakout Game in Java does not pass boolean value after calling remove() method

Tags: java, breakout

I have been following the CS106A lectures online and doing the assignments.  I've been stuck for a few days though on the breakout game because I cannot understand it's behavior.

Basically, I have built the environment, bricks, ball, paddle, edges, and I can get the ball to bounce around in the environment.  I can get the ball to even bounce off the bricks and I can even remove the bricks.  But I cannot get the ball to bounce off the bricks and remove the bricks at the same time.

If you look in my code, you will see that I have a method for reversing the direction of the ball.  This method takes a boolean value from my method that checks if the ball has collided with any of the objects in the environment.  If I do not include the method 'remove()' the ball will bounce off the bricks as expected.  If I do include that method, the ball will remove the bricks but not bounce off of them.  This indicates to me that the code is being read and returning the boolean value but the value is not changing the direction the ball is moving.

```
/*
 * File: Breakout.java
 * -------------------
 * Name:
 * Section Leader:
 * 
 * This file will eventually implement the game of Breakout.
 */

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import acm.graphics.GArc;
import acm.graphics.GLine;
import acm.graphics.GObject;
import acm.graphics.GOval;
import acm.graphics.GRect;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import acm.util.RandomGenerator;


public class Breakout extends GraphicsProgram {

/** Width and height of application window in pixels */
    public static final int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 600;

/** Dimensions of game board (usually the same) */
    private static final int WIDTH = APPLICATION_WIDTH;
    private static final int HEIGHT = APPLICATION_HEIGHT;

/** Dimensions of the paddle */
    private static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 60;
    private static final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 10;

/** Offset of the paddle up from the bottom */
    private static final int PADDLE_Y_OFFSET = 30;

/** Number of bricks per row */
    private static final int NBRICKS_PER_ROW = 10;

/** Number of rows of bricks */
    private static final int NBRICK_ROWS = 10;

/** Separation between bricks */
    private static final int BRICK_SEP = 4;

/** Width of a brick */
    private static final int BRICK_WIDTH =
      (WIDTH - (NBRICKS_PER_ROW - 1) * BRICK_SEP) / NBRICKS_PER_ROW;

/** Height of a brick */
    private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 8;

/** Radius of the ball in pixels */
    private static final int BALL_RADIUS = 10;

/** Offset of the top brick row from the top */
    private static final int BRICK_Y_OFFSET = 70;

/** Number of turns */
/** private static final int NTURNS = 3;*/

/* Method: run() */
/** Runs the Breakout program. */

    public void run() {
        init();
        createBall();
        createSides();
        createBlocks();
        createPaddle();
        addMouseListeners();
        waitForClick();
        while (BALL.getY() <= HEIGHT){
            play();
        }
    }

    public void init(){
        setSize(500,700);
    }

    private void createBlocks(){
        int BRICKS = 0;
        int ROWS = 0;
        while (ROWS != NBRICK_ROWS) {
            while (BRICKS != NBRICKS_PER_ROW){
                GRect BRICK = new GRect (BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
                BRICK.setLocation((BRICKS*(BRICK_SEP + BRICK_WIDTH)+BRICK_SEP), BRICK_Y_OFFSET + (ROWS*(BRICK_HEIGHT + BRICK_SEP)));
                BRICK.setFilled(true);
                if (ROWS == 0 || ROWS == 1){
                    BRICK.setColor(Color.RED);
                    BRICK.setFilled(true);}
                    else if (ROWS == 2 || ROWS == 3) {
                        BRICK.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                    }   
                    else if (ROWS == 4 || ROWS == 5){
                        BRICK.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }
                    else if (ROWS == 6 || ROWS == 7){
                        BRICK.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                    else if (ROWS == 8 || ROWS == 9){
                        BRICK.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                    }
                add(BRICK);
                BRICKS++;
            }
            ROWS++;
            BRICKS = 0;
        }
    }

    private void createSides(){
        add(rightSide);
        add(leftSide);
        add(topSide);
        add(bottomSide);
    }

    private void createPaddle(){
        PADDLE.setFilled(true);
        add(PADDLE, WIDTH/2 - (PADDLE_WIDTH/2), HEIGHT - PADDLE_Y_OFFSET);
    }

    private void createBall(){
        BALL.setFilled(true);
        BALL.setLocation(WIDTH/2 - 18, HEIGHT/2);
        add(BALL);
    }

    private void play(){
        /* Add Title Text or Lives or Score */
        ballMovement();
    }

    private void ballMovement(){
        BRICK_COUNT = (NBRICKS_PER_ROW*NBRICK_ROWS);
        while (BRICK_COUNT != 0){
            BALL.move(ballXVelocity(), ballYVelocity());
            pause(5);
            checkXCollision();
            checkYCollision();
        }
    }

    public int ballXVelocity(){
        boolean x = checkXCollision();
        if (x == true){
            BALL_X_VELOCITY = -INITIAL_X_VELOCITY;
            INITIAL_X_VELOCITY = BALL_X_VELOCITY;
        }
        else {BALL_X_VELOCITY = INITIAL_X_VELOCITY;}
        return BALL_X_VELOCITY;
    }

    public int ballYVelocity(){
        boolean y = checkYCollision();
        if (y == true){
            BALL_Y_VELOCITY = -INITIAL_Y_VELOCITY;
            INITIAL_Y_VELOCITY = BALL_Y_VELOCITY;
        }
        else {BALL_Y_VELOCITY = INITIAL_Y_VELOCITY;}
        return BALL_Y_VELOCITY;
    }

    private boolean checkXCollision(){
        double ballX = BALL.getX();
        double ballY = BALL.getY();
        GObject colObjLeft = getElementAt(ballX, ballY - BALL_RADIUS);
        GObject colObjRight = getElementAt(ballX + BALL_RADIUS*2, ballY- BALL_RADIUS);
        if (ballX <= 0 || ballX + (BALL_RADIUS*2) >= APPLICATION_WIDTH){
            return true;
        }
        else if (colObjLeft != null){

            return true;
        }
        else if (colObjRight != null){

            return true;
        }
        else {return false;}
    }

    private boolean checkYCollision(){
        double ballX = BALL.getX();
        double ballY = BALL.getY();
        GObject colObjTop = getElementAt(ballX+ BALL_RADIUS, ballY - 1);
        GObject colObjBot = getElementAt(ballX + BALL_RADIUS, ballY + (BALL_RADIUS*2) + 1);
        if(colObjBot == PADDLE){
            return true;
        } 
        else if (ballY <= 0){
            return true;
            }
        else if (colObjTop != null && colObjTop != BALL){
            remove(colObjTop);
            return true;
        }   
        else if (colObjBot != null && colObjBot != PADDLE && colObjBot != BALL){
            remove(colObjBot);
            return true;
        }
        else {return false;}
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        if (e != null){     
            int x = e.getX();
            PADDLE.setLocation(x - (PADDLE_WIDTH/2), HEIGHT - PADDLE_Y_OFFSET);
        }
    }

    /*public void paddleLocation(dx,dy);*/
        /*int x = */

    public GRect PADDLE = new GRect(PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
    private GArc BALL = new GArc(BALL_RADIUS*2, BALL_RADIUS*2, 0,360);
    /*private GOval BALL = new GOval(BALL_RADIUS*2, BALL_RADIUS*2);*/
    private int BRICK_COUNT;
    private int BALL_Y_VELOCITY;
    private int BALL_X_VELOCITY;
    private int INITIAL_Y_VELOCITY = 1;
    private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();
    private int INITIAL_X_VELOCITY = rgen.nextInt(2);
    private GLine rightSide = new GLine (WIDTH, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT );
    private GLine leftSide = new GLine (0, 0, 0, HEIGHT);
    private GLine topSide = new GLine (0, 0, WIDTH, 0);
    private GLine bottomSide = new GLine (0, HEIGHT, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your extra calls to `checkXCollision` and `checkYCollision` are the problem.

You call them directly as part of `ballMovement`, and each are also called inside the `Velocity` methods.

To get the params for `Ball.move`, you call the `Velocity` methods, which check for a collision and remove the brick. But, right after moving the ball, you're checking for collisions and removing again. So, when `ballMovement` gets run the next time, the bricks have already been removed, and the collision detection inside the `Velocity` methods doesn't work.

Since you're not doing anything with the collision return values in `ballMovement`, you probably don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, great first question.

```
while (BRICK_COUNT != 0){
     BALL.move(ballXVelocity(), ballYVelocity());
     pause(5);
     checkXCollision();
     checkYCollision();
}
```

I think the error is in calling `check*Collision()` in your main loop *and* in your `ball*Velocity()` methods.

If the collision is found in one of the `ball*Velocity()` methods, then the brick is removed, course reversed, and seems fine.

But if the collision is found in the direct calls to `check*Collision()`, then you're unable to reverse direction.

But I'm afraid the fix is going to be more than just removing these two lines. (But give that a shot. :) What happens **when the ball collides in a corner, both X and Y**? I think the fact that you're checking ball velocity in *two* different functions, possibly changing directions in two different functions, and not passing knowledge 'between them', that your collision code when the ball hits in a corner isn't correct. (`checkXCollision()`, called via `ballXVelocity()`, might remove a brick that `checkYCollision()`, called via `ballYVelocity()`, needs in order to determine if it needs to change direction.)

You might want to re-write the functions to calculate the X and Y collisions *simultaneously*, so you can remove one or two bricks as needed.

I hope this helps.